# Add onclick event to command field in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this update link in DetailsView.

```
<asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true" ShowCancelButton="false" ValidationGroup="VAL_1" />
```

When i click this link, its updates the content on the page. but i want to updates the content on the page and redirect to another page (ex: abc.aspx) after click on this.

How could i do this ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `ItemCommand` event:

in code behind:

```
protected void detailsview1_ItemCommand(Object sender, DetailsViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Update")
    {
        Response.Redirect("abc.aspx", false);
    }
}
```

In aspx:

```
<asp:DetailsView runat="server" 
     ID="detailsview1" 
     OnItemCommand="detailsview1_ItemCommand" ...
```

Comment: i have added your code into partial class. but its not worked. should i call this method from some where ?

Comment: Sorry I forgot the protected word

Comment: i have added it just now :). now page redirect is working. but content is not updating on page. there are some text fields on page data filling from database. i have changed data and click Update. page redirect is succeed. but my changes didn't updated.

Comment: Try `Response.Redirect("abc.aspx", false);` and/or `e.Handled = false;`